# Constant background polling in Android crashes app with java.lang.OutOfMemoryError

Tags: java, android, android-volley

I'm trying to keep a constant poll in the background of an android application to check whether the connection to another device is successful or fails, currently using a `Volley.newRequestQueue` inside a method in a class to perform a Ping test to the device. After leaving the app running for a while, whether any direct interaction with the app is made or not, it crashes with the following error

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: pthread_create (1040KB stack) failed: Try again
```

The poll currently fires every 5000ms (or 5 seconds).

Is there a better way to handle making a constant background polling/ping request?